# php count data from sql and array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need yours help with counting issues, I have array from browser SESSION

```
$co = array_unique($_SESSION['number']);
```

array will be like below

```
Array ( [0] => 0701 [1] => 0537 [2] => 0649 [3] => 0703 [4])
```

now i will use $co to perform SQL query

```
$result_eed = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT `number` FROM baza WHERE `Number`='$co'  AND `Number` NOT LIKE  '%ERROR%'"));
```

Now is my question how to return sum of all findings not separate value for each array. I need to have ONE number for all value from array, sum

Comment: You should *really* consider switching to MySQLi or PDO.  P.S. Chaining `mysql_fetch_assoc` and `mysql_query` like that is bad practice.  You should be checking if `mysql_query` threw any errors before trying to fetch its rows.

Answer (score 2):

First off `$co` is an *array*, so you can't do `` "`Number` = '$co'" ``.  You'll need to use:

```
"`Number` IN (" . implode(',', $co) . ")"
```

To get the *sum*, just use the `SUM()` function:

```
SELECT SUM(Number) as Total
```

Comment: $result_eed = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT SUM( DISTINCT Customer) as Total FROM report WHERE `Name` IN ('. implode(',', $co) .')  AND `Customer` NOT LIKE  '%ERROR%'"));
echo $result_eed[Total];     and still this same, no results

Answer (score 1):

You should use `IN` clause in MySQL. For that convert your array in appropriate string.

```
$new_String = "";
foreach($co as $c){
    $new_String .= "'"$c."',";
}
$new_String = rtrim($new_String);

$result_eed = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(`number`) FROM baza WHERE `Number`IN ($new_String)  AND `Number` NOT LIKE  '%ERROR%'"));
```

Check [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) reference:

**PS: I think @Rocket's solution is better. You can also use `implode` (built in php function to convert array in to string).**